# How to capture from a dynamically built form with table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am building a site for a restaurant and built a table within a form dynamically with php and mysql to show each menu item. Each row has a quantity input, followed by the item and description etc and ends with an "Add to Order" button. What I need to do is when the button is pressed, send the quantity and the id of the item to a session variable. I have seen suggestions of using an array for the input id's wasn't sure how to handle them I guess.

```
$d=date('N');
$sql2="CALL SP_GET_MENU_ITEM('entree', '$d');";
$result=mysql_query($sql2, $conn2);
if(!$result)
    die(mysql_error());
$count=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $n=$row['itemName'];
    $de=$row['description'];
    $i=$row['ingredient'];
    $p=$row['price'];
    $dr=$row['dietRestrict'];
    $f=$row['path'];

    /*$pic="CALL SP_GET_MENU_IMAGE('$n');";
    $picTry=mysql_query($pic, $conn);
    $picResult=mysql_fetch_assoc($picTry);
    $f=$picTry['path'];*/

    print '<tr><td>
    <input type="number" min="1" name="quantity" style="width:40px;" /></td>
    <td class="itemDes">';
    print "<h2>".$n."</h2>";
    print "<img src='../admin/menu/".$f."' alt='foodPic'></td>";
    print "</td><td><p>description: ".$de."<br>ingredients: ".$i."</td><td>".$dr."</td><td>".$p."</td></p></td><td>
    <input type='button' onclick= 'doit()' value='Add to Order' class='btn'/>
}
```

It populates the tables correctly right now, and the function doit() [which just calls an alert] calls correctly when any of the buttons are pressed. I was thinking I'd have to pass variables into it i.e. `<onclick="doit(quantity.value))">` so how would i get that `quantity.value` to work??

Comment: Try: `onclick="return doit(document.getElementById("itemID").value());"`

Comment: Will that return the value of that just that row? right now each quantity input would have the same id, I assume that will affect it??

Comment: Try: onclick="doit($( "input[name='quantity']" ).val())”  This should work.  Le t me know if it works.

Comment: FYI, Standards dictate that you should never reuse an id in your html. The whole idea of an ID is to be a unique identifier of an element. If you want to reuse an ID for css purposes, you need to use the class attribute instead.

Comment: If you cold do a small fiddle with html element we can help better to solve the issue.

Comment: the input[name=quantity] did not work. what fiddle would we need to make??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'this' to access the current element, so if you were to use doit(this.value), this.value would equal 'Add to Order'

From here you can use dom methods to find the element in the related context. It's hard to tell from your code as I don't have a full picture of the HTML, but you might try this:

```
doit(this.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.value)
```

This gets the container of your button, which is a td, and then gets the container of that, which is a tr, then gets the first child element of that, which is the first td contained by that tr, and then the value of the first child of that which is the quantity input. (Is your head spinning yet?)

Comment: I follow, however it returns an undefined value.
my doit function is as follows

function doit(number){alert('clicked ' +number)};

and get "clicked undefined" as the alert

Comment: It's likely you'll need to use a different combination of parentElement and firstChild, depending on your HTML, can you add a complete table to your question?

Comment: Well I started condensing my code by removing unnecessary line breaks, and this method started working. Guess I should be more careful with my style of coding. Thank you very much

Comment: Oh, thats my bad, in HTML whitespace is considered a child. Try using 'firstElementChild' instead. I'll edit my answer to match. Beware, firstElementChild requires IE9+ so if you need to support IE8 you should use firstChild with no whitespace.

Comment: Also I believe IE8 has issues with 'parentElement' so if you need to support IE8 you'll want to use 'parent' and once again make sure there is zero whitespace between your tags in your html...

Comment: Yeah, lesson learned on white spaces lol. I will check out the IE8 support, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Since you are creating the elements dynamically, the following expression would register a click event handler on the button after the dom has rendered. This way you do not need to register click within the dom.

```
$(document).on("click","input:button",function()
{
    alert($("input:text[name=quantity]").val());
});
```